# Is it possible to use CORS or JSONP to access the OpenID Provider Configuration?

Tags: javascript, cors, pingfederate

I'm attempting to use a XHR/Ajax call to our PingFederate configuration (/.well-known/openid-configuration) but I'm getting a cross-domain error.

Its imperative that JavaScript clients be able to call this URL since the entire OIDC flow is possible with a client side JavaScript application. Therefore, this endpoint needs to be accessible on a domain other than the IdP and ideally without a separate server side proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (September 2018):** PingFederate (from version 9.0 and up) now has simple out of the box configuration for enabling CORS. For more details, see:

- https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=tpw1564002965961.html
- https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=ird1564002990806.html

---

**Original Answer:**

The [CrossOriginFilter Jetty filter](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter) can be enabled in PingFederate to support this.